# Use named paths inside a scope for intersections outside the scope?

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, scoping

I need to:

1. draw an ellipse,
2. name it so I can intersect it later,
3. clip it.

To accomplish 3, it seems most appropriate to use a `scope`, but this means that I cannot accomplish 2. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-2.0, 0.0) -- (2.0,0.0);
  \draw[->,name path=yaxis] ( 0.0,-2.0) -- (0.0,2.0);
  \draw[name path=ellipse] (-1.0,0.0) ellipse (1.5 and 0.6);
  \path[name intersections={of=ellipse and yaxis,by=x}];
  \draw[red,fill=red] (x) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

where the red circle indicates the intersection point. 
This accomplishes 1 and 2, but not 3, for which I would need something like

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-2.0, 0.0) -- (2.0,0.0);
  \draw[->,name path=yaxis] ( 0.0,-2.0) -- (0.0,2.0);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-2.0,-2.0) rectangle (2.0,2.0);
    \draw[name path=ellipse] (-1.0,0.0) ellipse (1.5 and 0.6);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

giving

[image]

but due to the scope, I cannot refer to the path and determine the intersection point and draw it as a red circle.

So what is the best way to clip the ellipse but still be able to use it to determine an intersection point? Is there a way to make some "properties" from within a `scope` global?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you looking for `name path global`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->] (-2.0, 0.0) -- (2.0,0.0);
  \draw[->,name path=yaxis] ( 0.0,-2.0) -- (0.0,2.0);
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (-2.0,-2.0) rectangle (2.0,2.0);
    \draw[name path global=ellipse] (-1.0,0.0) ellipse (1.5 and 0.6);
  \end{scope}
  \draw[name intersections={of=ellipse and yaxis,by=x},red,fill=red] (x) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, didn't expect such a quick resolution of my problem. I wonder why `name path global` is not mentioned in the manual where `scope` is explained.

Comment: @user1362373 `/tikz/name path global` is mentioned on p. 142 of pgfmanual v3.1.4b, along with the warning "Handle with care". (So far I had no issues using it, but inside the library it is mentioned that "the `name path global` is not reset properly - and some following `name path` will append to it rather that reset it.".)